# How do you Symmetrize an Armature?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I've been working on a tutorial in Blender, and the tutorial says for me to press "F3" to symmetrize it, but when I do that, it instead changes the computer's brightness. Are there any other ways for me to do that?

Here is the tutorial I am working on, particularly the moment I am currently in...
https://youtu.be/XkiWBSSuxLw?t=772

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit* mode, select all (or select the bones you want to symmetrize) and *Armature panel > Symmetrize*. <kbd>F3</kbd> is his shortcut for search, it may not be yours.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are in edit mode (armature selected), there is a menu called armature, inside you will find Symmetrize.

[image]

If you are using a laptop, you proably need to use the <kbd>Function</kbd> key on your keyboard to open the F3 search Menu